# Multiple files for modularizing vscode settings

Tags: visual-studio-code

I was wondering if there's a way to import other json files into your vscode `settings.json`.

I thought for sure I had found a way to do this in the past but I forgot to attempt to implement it and now I can't find a way to do it.

For example, let's say I have a bunch of editor settings, but then I also have color custommizations as well as certain extension settings.

What I'd like is something like an `editor-settings.json` and a `token-colors.json` file that I can include in my main `settings.json` file with something like

```
{
    "source": [
       "./editor-settings.json",
       "./token-colors.json"
     ]
}
```

Hopefully I've explained well what I'm looking for and someone can help me find it.

Thanks for taking the time to read and respond. :)

Comment: The feature you're looking for doesn't seem to exist in VS Code, but there are some discussions around this problem. You might be interested in this issue: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/40233

Comment: I think [this](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/15909) might hit on it more - that one is focused specifically on "local" workspace settings

Comment: I'm exploring https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=swellaby.workspace-config-plus to satisfy my similar need.